# Subsonic primary key error

Tags: subsonic

I'm getting the following error in subsonic:

Can't decide which property to consider the Key when trying to run this code:

```
var book = repository.Single<Libro>(l=>l.Prefix==capitulo[0]);
```

I already rerun the t4 templates and still get the same error. Any advice? thanks.

Comment: Can you describe more what you're trying to do? What's the value of capitulo[0]? What's the error you're getting? We need a lot more info before we can help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, here is the stack trace if it helps.

[InvalidOperationException: Can't decide which property to consider the Key - you can create one called 'ID' or mark one with SubSonicPrimaryKey attribute]
   SubSonic.Extensions.Objects.ToSchemaTable(Type type, IDataProvider provider) +1066
   SubSonic.DataProviders.DbDataProvider.FindOrCreateTable(Type type) +65
   SubSonic.DataProviders.DbDataProvider.FindOrCreateTable() +39
   SubSonic.Repository.SimpleRepository.Single(Expression`1 expression) +115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I do not know the speaking english, I speak Spanish... Your problem is because the database is poorly constructed... there is an error with the definition of primary and foreign keys